# Mysteries of xinitrc - what can and cannot be there

Tags: xorg

Please,
can someone shed some light for me on `.xinitrc` file? I struggle to find a good manual to answer a couple of my practical questions:

- It declared itself as general Bash script but in fact it is not.
- Why some command require `exec` and some not?
- What is this `exec` command anyway?
- Is it a binary or a syntactic construct specific to `xinitrc`?
- What can be run by exec and what not?
- How to set environmental variables correctly?

Most users of mainstream distros does not have to even know about `xinitrc`, and same was true for me, until I had to setup Kodi "makeshift" shell; using super minimalist window manager TWM and launching Kodi full screen, because `kodi-standalone` shell does not work for me.

But back to the `xinitrc`:

Working example:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/twm &
sleep 1
exec xterm
```

Why `twm` and `sleep` do not need `exec` but `xterm` does?

Not working example:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/twm &
sleep 1
exec WINDOWING=x11 /usr/bin/kodi -geometry +0+0
```

Here `exec` executed only `WINDOWING=x11` but ignored the rest of the line. I made it working only by wrapping `WINDOWING=x11 /usr/bin/kodi -geometry +0+0` into another Bash script, this time an ordinary one, and that one put as the only argument to `exec`; then it finally worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22869637/1068283

Comment: Why do you use `exec`? just run it on this way: `WINDOWING=x11 /usr/bin/kodi -geometry +0+0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exec` command replaces the current shell process with the process resulting from executing the given command.  Without `exec`, control would be handed back to the waiting shell session once the command terminates. With `exec`, the current shell is replaced, so no further commands would be run from your script from that point on.

The `~/.xinitrc` file is a shell script. It starts the window manager (`twm` in your case), and possibly other X11 clients that you may want to start initially (like `xterm` or some other terminal, and `xeyes`, obviously).  There is no special syntax for this script apart from that it should be a valid script (since it's run by a shell script interpreter).

In your first example, you use

```
exec xterm
```

This replaces the current shell process with `xterm`. Without `exec`, you would have the exact same *visible* effect, but the `.xinitrc` script would hang around in the background waiting for `xterm` to terminate before itself terminating (since that was the last command in the file).

Note that if you had done `exec twm`, the shell would have replaced itself with `twm` which means that it would not be able to run the other commands in the script.  This is why you instead start `twm` as a background process (with `&` at the end).  The sleep is there to allow `twm` to start up properly before starting the terminal.  I don't think this is strictly necessary.  In fact, if you don't need window decorations or to be able to move windows around or resize them, there is no need to even run `twm` or any other window manager (at least not for running a full screen `xterm`).

In your second example, you use

```
exec WINDOWING=x11 /usr/bin/kodi -geometry +0+0
```

Now, the `exec` command can't be used to set environment variables like that.  Instead, you would set and export the `WINDOWING` variable *before* invoking `kodi`:

```
export WINDOWING=x11
exec /usr/bin/kodi -geometry +0+0
```